# Angular Components does not work with Promise and Service

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise, angular-components

I have a really strange problem with Angular Components calling a service.
For example, i have a simple service with some mockup data as an array inside. The i add two methods, one synchron and one asynchron which returns a promise (if i correct understood).
Now a have a angular component which is well loaded in a example application.
On the frontend i have two buttons, one for each method in the service.
If i press now the button "btn1" the list is well loaded, all works fine.
If i now press the button "btn2" i see in the console that the service returns all data correctly, but the list in the frontend will not be loaded.

**Service**

```
var myItems = [
  {id: 1, name: "item1"},
  {id: 2, name: "item2"}
];

function ItemsService($q) { // inject the $q service
    this.$q = $q;
}

ItemsService.prototype = {
    loadItems: function () {
        return myItems;
    },

    loadItemsAsync: function () {
        var $qme = this.$q; // if i do not this, "this.$q" is undefined
        return this.$q.resolve(myItems);
    }
};

module.exports = {
    ItemsService: ItemsService
}
```

**Controller**

```
function Foo(ItemsService) {
    this.itemsService = ItemsService;
}

Foo.prototype = {
    loadItems: function () {
        this.items = this.itemsService.loadItems();
    },
    loadItemsAsync: function () {
        this.itemsService.loadItemsAsync().then(
            function (response) {
                this.items = response;
                console.log('data->' + this.items + ' -> ' + this.items[0].name);
            },
            function (error) {
                console.log('error->' + error); // ignore
            }
        );
    }
};
```

**Component HTML**

```
<section>
    <button id="btn1" ng-click="$ctrl.loadItems()">Load</button>
    <button id="btn2" ng-click="$ctrl.loadItemsAsync()">Load Async</button>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.items">{{item.id}} // {{item.name}}</li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

In future i want to replace the code in the service method of "loadItemsAsync" with a service call, but actually nothing works.

**Future planned service method code**

```
loadTreasuriesAsync: function () {
    var $qme = this.$q;
    return this.$http.get(this.url).then(
        function (response) {
            return $qme.resolve(response.data);
        },
        function (error) {
            throw error;
        }
    );
}
```

I also tried this service call, but it also returns a promise object.

```
loadItems: function () {
    return this.$http.get(this.url).then(function (response) {
        return response.data;
    });
},
```

Can anyone help me finding a solution?

Comment: You have `function (response)` but you expect `data` to contain something... and `$http` already returns a promise so using `$q` with it is redundant.

Comment: Thats equal. The problem is, that the frontend only shows the list if i use a synchron call.

Comment: Btw I would rename the title to "How to fake a Promise & how to return a Promise into a Component Controller. Because Components do work with services and promises.

Comment: I do not want to fake a promise, i only want to see my data in the page itself, not only in the console!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.items = response;`

this does not exist anymore in the context. Try to save the context previously either by an outside variable (i.e. _this) or use arrow functions if you have those available.

Comment: This was a good tip and a part of the solution. In opposite to FountainJS, the data has to be loaded into the $scope variable instead into this. This can be done with a ()={} arrow function.